# CSqlDataProvider yii sorting after manipulating data

Tags: php, sorting, yii

I am showing data from CSqlDataProvider with pagination, I want to add sorting for my results 
 my situation is-
 I get the data with

```
    $dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sqlAll, array(
                'totalItemCount'=>$count,
                'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>$pageSize,),
                'params' => $params
            ));
```

after I get the results I calculate 2 more fields to show(which are not extracted with the $sqlAll query) and sort according to them
My problem is: I only get the $pagesize amount of results, and what happens is that the sorting is per $pagesize results and not from all the results.
 can I add the calculated fields to the CSqlDataProvider or pagination?

Comment: Are you by any chance using limit in your SQL query? Because you should leave that to the dataprovider.

Comment: The limit is done by the pagination and $pagesize

Comment: Ok, then I recommend trying method 1 of my answer. Though it could lead to complex queries. It's the most scalable solution. Only use method 2 if you are sure your result recordset will stay relatively small (or risk bad performance).

Comment: it comes out as a very complex and time consuming query...

Comment: Well I guess you could post a question about the query and how to optimize it's performance ;) Maybe there is an easy solution or workaround for that one. Or maybe some caching can be applied. Either way I'd have to see the query (or it's principle) to help out with that. I don't see any real viable solutions for this question  other than the one's I gave (but that could just be me ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the calculated fields in one of two ways:

1. Calculate the results of the two fields directly in the query and [sort on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864784/sorting-with-csqldataprovider-in-yii?rq=1#answer-20495634).
2. Use a CArrayDataProvider and fill it with the data from the associative array of the query result (get this result using the [DAO](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao)) to which you added the two fields "manually".